# Create std::string from int8_t array

Tags: c++, casting, char, integer, stdstring

In some code `int8_t[]` type is used instead of `char[]`.

```
int8_t title[256] = {'a', 'e', 'w', 's'};
std::string s(title); // compile error: no corresponding constructor
```

How to properly and safely create a `std::string` from it?

When I will do `cout << s;` I want that it print `aews`, as if `char[]` type was passed to the constructor.

Comment: See this question ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961443/convert-from-uint8-t-to-char-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are

```
int8_t title[256] = { 'a', 'e', 'w', 's' };
std::string s( reinterpret_cast<char *>( title ) );
std::cout << s << '\n';
```

Or you may use also

```
std::string s( reinterpret_cast<char *>( title ), 4 );
```

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea without an explicit null terminator in the array.

Comment: @dave And why do you have decided that there is no null terminating character?

Comment: There should be 252 null terminators in that array. :-)

Comment: @dave I though the same thing and then remembered that all missing initializers are set to `0`, so it has 252 null terminators in it.

Comment: Ah right, didn't see the 256 size. That's ok then in this case

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` like other containers can be constructed using a pair of iterators. This constructor will use implicit conversions if available, such as converting `int8_t` to `char`.

```
int8_t title[256] = {'a', 'e', 'w', 's'};
std::string s(std::begin(title), std::end(title));
```

Note that this solution will copy the whole array, including the unused bytes. If the array is often much larger than it needs to be, you can look for the null terminator instead

```
int8_t title[256] = {'a', 'e', 'w', 's'};
auto end = std::find(std::begin(title), std::end(title), '\0');
std::string s(std::begin(title), end);
```