# Is cast from uint8_t* to char* acceptable

Tags: c, uint8t, uint8array, chararray

Concerning this question

[Convert from uint8_t * to char * in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961443/convert-from-uint8-t-to-char-in-c)

The suggestion was simply to cast with (char*). Why is this acceptable in this context? Or did the responder just take the question literally?

Casting unsigned (depending on the implementation) to signed feels dubious.

Comment: You're generally allowed to cast any pointer type to `char *`. It's the most fine-grained pointer type, and can point to any object.

Comment: _"Casting unsigned ... to signed feels dubious."_ -- To be clear, you are casting a _pointer_ to an unsigned integer type to a _pointer_ to `char` (which may or may not be signed). This is different from casting between unsigned and signed integer types.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the nature of your concern?  As I commented on the linked question, type conversion is the whole purpose of casting. If you suppose that the conversion in question makes sense at all, then why would casting in particular be worse than any other means for accomplishing it?

Comment: @Barmar "generally allowed to cast any pointer type to char *" is more like "generally allowed to cast any _object_ pointer type to `char *`"  Casting a function pointer to `char *` may lose important information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, it is allowed to access a variable of a given type through a pointer to the signed or unsigned version of that that type.

This is specified in section 6.5p7 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
> expression that has one of the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - **a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object**,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a
>   subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

A `uint8_t` is an alias for an `unsigned char` (at least, on systems where `CHAR_BIT` is 8), so it is allowed to convert an `uint8_t *` to a `char *` and subsequently dereference the resulting pointer.

Note also that, per the last bullet point above, using a pointer *any* character type is allowed to access any kind of object.

Comment: Re “A `uint8_t` is an alias for an `unsigned char`”: I do not think that is required. It could be an alias for `char`, if `char` is unsigned. Or it could be an alias for some extended type the C implementation defines that behaves like `unsigned char` except that it is a different type. Just go with the “a character type” item.

Comment: There's also 6.3.2.3 §7 which is in sync with the "strict aliasing rules" quoted in this answer: _"When a pointer to
an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte
of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the
remaining bytes of the object."_ Meaning any pointer to object type may be converted to a pointer of character type safely.